# MVC 3 Plugin assemblies, how to use it when loaded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am working on a plugin-interface for widgets in a MVC 3 application. 
The Widgets should contain there own models, views and the controlers. Then I want to be able to just drop a (mvc-project "Widget") dll into the plugin folder in my main-application.
But how do i refer to it when its loaded dynamically? I cant do like myapp.plugin.clock then i get compilation error the assembly is loaded in rumtime!? should i use dynamic?

This is the code i use to load the plugins and it seems to work. Now i dont know how to use the loaded assembly in a good way, any ideas?

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.PluginActivator), "Initialize")]

public class PluginActivator
{
    private static readonly DirectoryInfo PluginFolderInfo;

    static PluginActivator()
    {
        PluginFolderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/plugins"));
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        CopyPluginDlls(PluginFolderInfo, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DynamicDirectory);
        LoadPluginAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DynamicDirectory);
    }

    private static void CopyPluginDlls(DirectoryInfo sourceFolder, string destinationFolder)
    {
        foreach (var plug in sourceFolder.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, plug.Name)))
            {
                File.Copy(plug.FullName, Path.Combine(destinationFolder, plug.Name), false);
            }
        }
    }

    public  static void LoadPluginAssemblies(string dynamicDirectory)
    {
        foreach (var plug in Directory.GetFiles(dynamicDirectory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(plug));
            BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(assembly);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a plugin folder instead of just copying to the bin folder?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way. Since you have managed to load assemblies from "~/plugins" folder. The next task is to implement custom VirtualPathProvider and register all virtual paths. I managed to implemented a ASP.NET MVC3 Razor plugin architecture with the help of this post : http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/. You can take it for reference and implement your own framework. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define some extension points using interfaces combined with an inversion of control container.

I've described the approach here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386674/ASP-NET-MVC-3-plug-in-architecture-using-Griffin-M